# Change back format after pasting code in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

This question is related to the following question but not the same.
[Outlook 2010 changes formatting after pasting text](https://superuser.com/questions/338946/outlook-2010-changes-formatting-after-pasting-text)

My email are text and code mixed. After I paste **inline** code, the following text would follow the style of code. For example, I copy `select * from table` into the outlook editor, then the following text would change its style to code style.

What I want it the code uses code's style, the text always uses text style. Is there a way to do that?

This question is for Outlook, but not limited to Outlook.